# Waiting for WebBrowser to load in a timer

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I'm creating a simple auto surfing app to learn the WebBrowser object.

I've got a list of 23 URL's that I'm surfing every few seconds.

The app is simple, go to a forum and open the FORM to add new message (without sending it)
and keep going until you get to the end of the list.

My problem is that the code `forumAction.FillOutFormIn(webBrowser1.Document);` executes in the wrong site.

I think that this happened because the document is not ready.

So is there a way to stop the timer excuting code until the document is ready?

Here is the `TIMER TICK` function:

```
//I start is in 21 for faster testing.
int timesToRun = 21;
    private void Time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            Console.WriteLine(timesToRun.ToString());
            string currentSite = siteList.GetSiteFromIndex(timesToRun);

            webBrowser1.Document.Window.Navigate(currentSite);

            //I think I need to wait here until the document is ready

            //this line of code doesn't run on timeToRun = 22
            forumAction.FillOutFormIn(webBrowser1.Document);

            Console.WriteLine(webBrowser1.Url);
            timerLabel1.Text = siteList.SiteLists.Count + ">" + timesToRun + "";

            if (timesToRun >= siteList.SiteLists.Count - 1)
            {
                enableControls(true);
                timesToRun = 0;
                timer.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("done");

            }

            timesToRun++;          
    }
```

(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply code the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted) event of the control.

This will allow you to restart the timer when the page is loaded.

```
webBrowser1.Navigated += WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
timesToRun = 22;

private void Time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.stop();
    webBrowser1.Document.Window.Navigate(url);
}

void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    timesToRun--;
    if(timesToRun > 0)
    {
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: this work but when it get to the end the timer start over even afther i say (when timesToRun is 23) set timesToRun to 0 and stop the timer

Answer (score 1):

Add an event like this

```
You could disable your timer in your Time_tick function, 

timer1.Enabled = false;
```

then re-enable it in the doc completed event:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(timesToRun > 0) 
    { 
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: this work but when it get to the end the timer start over even afther i say (when timesToRun is 23) set timesToRun to 0 and stop the timer.

Answer (score 0):

//I start is in 21 for faster testing.
int timesToRun = 21;
    private void Time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
        Console.WriteLine(timesToRun.ToString());
        string currentSite = siteList.GetSiteFromIndex(timesToRun);

        webBrowser1.Document.Window.Navigate(currentSite);

        //I think I need to wait here until the document is ready

        //this line of code doesn't run on timeToRun = 22
        forumAction.FillOutFormIn(webBrowser1.Document);

        Console.WriteLine(webBrowser1.Url);
        timerLabel1.Text = siteList.SiteLists.Count + ">" + timesToRun + "";

        if (timesToRun >= siteList.SiteLists.Count - 1)
        {
            enableControls(true);
            timesToRun = 0;
            timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("done");

        }

        timesToRun++;          
}
```

the timmer coad isthis